# Show QApplication::applicationDisplayName only on main window?

Tags: qt

When setting up my Qt application, I set its display name like this:

```
QApplication::setApplicationDisplayName("Application Name");
```

As a result this name is used to automatically compose the title of the main window, like e.g. `example.txt[*] - Application Name` using the main window's `windowFilePath`and `windowModified` properties. So far this is exactly what I want.

My problem is that the application name is also appended to the title of every other little window or dialog that my application shows, even just message boxes and the like. I think this is weird and would like to show the application name only on the main window. Is this possible without just creating the complete main window title manually?

Comment: If you just want to assign a title to the main window, you can use `setWindowTitle(QString)`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I would like to avoid duplicating Qt's logic of how the main window title is composed (file name, modification indicator, application name).

Comment: @LionKing That's painfully obvious... **and completely unhelpful.** Qt dynamically synthesizes the main window title in a platform-specific manner. Reduplicating that logic manually across *every* single Qt application ever would be counter-productive in the extreme.